# How to close dropdown box with Jquery when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this dropdown box, I would like to close it when clicking outside of it, how can I get it?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();

        $("#actionStatus").html("");


        });
        $("body:not(ul.nav li.dropdown)").hover(function(){
$("ul.nav li.dropdown").find('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
});

    $("#btnSendOption").click(function(){
        var data = $("#frmUserOption").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/users.php",
            data: data,
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#actionStatus").html("");
                $("input[type='radio']").attr('checked', false);
                $('.dropdown-menu').delay(1000).fadeOut();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#actionStatus").html("<div class='alertMsg alertMsg-danger'>Error, try again later</div>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share html code and if you can share jsfiddle link.

Comment: `$("*").not(".dropdown").click` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("body:not(ul.nav li.dropdown)").hover(function(){
    $("ul.nav li.dropdown").find('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: Hi Devil, this is not working as I have a conflict when code is executed, please check the edited code.

Comment: I found the issue, I had to use div instead of body. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this: (didnt test it)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("body").one("click",":not('ul.nav li.dropdown')", function(){
             $this.find('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
        });
        $this.find('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();
        $("#actionStatus").html("");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi reyaner, this is not working as I have a conflict when code is executed, please check the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple jsbin for you with an example of what I think you need. I added some simple html as reference just guessing what you needed...

http://jsbin.com/bodoxixa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi Scott, this is not working as I have a conflict when code is executed, please check my edited and full code.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the conflict?

Comment: I've tried adding your code already which belongs to the first part of full code, but seems something is not working correctly, so when I remove the part from close by clicking outside, script executes well but it doesn't close outside obviously, and when I insert the close part, then script doesn't execute properly.. I used the part from Devil in current code as you can notice, but even with script is not working, I guess there must be something wrong in syntax, or maybe in code, cause I changed positions for the close part but is not working well in any case.

Comment: I dont see any problems with my solution or the one you have posted. See link [link](http://jsbin.com/zimiforu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Maybe with these });.. I am not sure cause I still have the problem, where can I check that syntax is correct?

Comment: If you are using firefox try firebug, or in chrome use developer tools. See if there are any errors in the console when you refresh the page.

Comment: Scott I found the issue, I had to use $("div:not(ul.nav li.dropdown)") instead of $("body:not(ul.nav li.dropdown)").. body was the issue! Very appreciated for your help!