# Dropdown jQuery box to close after clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to get that a dropdown box closes after clicking outside of it with jquery. I've tried the below code already but seems something is not working correctly, so when I remove the part from "body: not(ul.nav li.dropdown)", the script executes well but it doesn't close outside obviously, and when I insert the close part, the script doesn't execute properly. What can be wrong in this syntax or in code that is avoiding both closing and execution to work correctly together?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').click(function() {
            jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();

            $("#actionStatus").html("");


            });
            $("body:not(ul.nav li.dropdown)").hover(function(){
$("ul.nav li.dropdown").find('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
});

        $("#btnSendOption").click(function(){
            var data = $("#frmUserOption").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/users.php",
                data: data,
                success: function( data ) {
                    $("#actionStatus").html("");
                    $("input[type='radio']").attr('checked', false);
                    $('.dropdown-menu').delay(1000).fadeOut();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $("#actionStatus").html("<div class='alertMsg alertMsg-danger'>Error, try again later</div>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you've made second post about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203088/how-to-close-dropdown-box-with-jquery-when-clicking-outside/25203215#25203215

Comment: Hey Zentoaku, sorry I am almost new here, I thought this way would be easier to find the answers to the question with a new post as code is different.

Comment: Edit your last post as question remains the same.

Comment: Ok I already did, but do I have to wait for the guys to reply now?.. how the people in the forum see that I edited the code in first post? Answers in first post are not correct, so please do not put that ansers are correct...

Comment: Interested people will check it anyway. Just wait with patience :)

Comment: BTW do you have any clue on the answer? :)

Comment: Focus on first thread. You have answers there. One of them should fine or you just need to adapt it a little bit. Also post there information about confilcts that you have. I'll no longer answer you in this thread as it is duplicate.